Can I ask for a spelling check of some text using a question?
I know that on a lot of SE sites, simple "homework" questions are discouraged. I don't speak Italian, but I have a song text that I need to check the spelling of (as I'm pretty sure it's wrong!) Can I do that through a question, or would it be best to get help in chat?

Welcome to Italian.SE!
I see nothing wrong in asking a question about spelling, so long as it's “general” enough. The spelling of Italian is quite conservative, although not completely fixed along time; on the other hand, it is quite often corrupted when going abroad for a variety of reasons.
Rather than just showing the text, you should better point at the spots where you are having doubts, in order to show you did some research before asking.
Let's wait for other opinions, with comments, votes (up or down) or other answers.

SE language sites don't want spelling, or other questions about "whole" poems.
You can show the whole text as "background information." But then ask only one or two spelling, or other questions where Google translate or other sources seem to give you conflicting advice. SE responders will give you answers to at least those questions, sometimes more.
Here is an example where I wrote both an English poem and a German translation that was incorrect. I asked about one aspect regarding my greatest doubt, and got a translation with (by my count) four additional corrections.
